# Вывод в один массив данных из двух разных таблиц - как сделать?

Tags: массивы, php

Требуется вывести данные сотрудника для редактирования.

БД сотрудник

БД доступы сотрудника

Пробовал так:

```
$json_output = array();
$result_staff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$_POST['id']."'" ,$db);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result_staff) > 0) {
        $row_staff = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff);

        $result_access_staff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM access_staff WHERE id_staff = '".$_POST['id']."'" ,$db);

                                    while ($access_staff = mysql_fetch_array($result_access_staff)) {
                                        $str .= sprintf( "'%s' => '%s', ",$access_staff['vid_access'],$access_staff['access']);// моя попытка
                                        $options_staff = "".substr_replace($str, '', strrpos($str, ','))."";//моя попытка
                                    }

                                $json_output = array('succes'=>1, 'name_staff'=>''.iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $row_staff['name']).'', 'email_staff'=>''.$row_staff['email'].'', 'post_staff'=>''.iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $row_staff['post_staff']).'', $options_staff);  
                            }
                    echo json_encode($json_output);
                    exit;
```

Получился результат такой:

```
{"succes":1,"name_staff":"Андрей","email_staff":"a.test@mail.ru","post_staff":"Менеджер","0":"'access_analitic' => '0', 'access_tools' => '0', 'access_balance' => '0', 'access_status' => '0', 'give_lids' => '0', 'del_lids' => '0', 'edit_lids' => '0', 'add_lids' => '1', 'view_lids' => '1'"}
```

Надо так:

```
{"succes":1,"name_staff":"Андрей","email_staff":"a.test@mail.ru","post_staff":"Менеджер","access_analitic:0, 'access_tools': 0, 'access_balance':0, 'access_status':0, 'give_lids':0, 'del_lids':0, 'edit_lids':0, 'add_lids':1, 'view_lids':1"}
```

Как сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста...

Comment: `"'%s' => '%s', "` заменить на `"'%s':%s, "`, только сдается мне, вам нормальный json нужен на выходе, а не json-co-строкой-в-json

Comment: Ок, работает, но тперь вопрос: откуда берется "0":

    "0":"access_analitic:0, 'access_tools': 0, 'access_balance':0, 'access_status':0, 'give_lids':0, 'del_lids':0, 'edit_lids':0, 'add_lids':1, 'view_lids':1"

Comment: `$json_output = array('succes'=>1, ... $options_staff);` заменить на 
`$json_output = array('succes'=>1, ... 'options_staff' => $options_staff);`

Comment: Что-то получились те же яйца, только в профиль =) 

    email_staff: "a.text@mail.ru"
    name_staff: "дима"
    options_staff: "'access_analitic':0, 'access_tools':0, 'access_balance':0, 'access_status':0, 'give_lids':0, 'del_lids':0, 'edit_lids':0, 'add_lids':1, 'view_lids':1"
    post_staff: "Менеджер"
    succes: 1

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, так, в чем конкретно различия с желаемым?

Comment: В том, что массив идет нормально? Но вот именно к дополнительным данным, которые вставляются в массив зачем-то заносится   "ключь":"'данные1':1,'данные2':2"и т.д. Должно быть продолжение просто первых данных.

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, ну я первым же комментарием сказал, что, скорее всего, вышеприведенное "надо так" не нужно.

    while ($access_staff = mysql_fetch_array($result_access_staff)) {
        $accessType = $access_staff['vid_access'];
        $accessGranted = $access_staff['access'])
        $options_staff[$accessType] = $accessGranted;
    }